# Byte Array in Python

Tags: python, byte, gevent

How can I represent a byte array (like in Java with byte[]) in Python? I'll need to send it over the wire with gevent.

```
byte key[] = {0x13, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00};
```

Answer (score 95, accepted):

In Python 3, we use the `bytes` object, also known as `str` in Python 2.

```
# Python 3
key = bytes([0x13, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00])

# Python 2
key = ''.join(chr(x) for x in [0x13, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00])
```

I find it more convenient to use the `base64` module...

```
# Python 3
key = base64.b16decode(b'130000000800')

# Python 2
key = base64.b16decode('130000000800')
```

You can also use literals...

```
# Python 3
key = b'\x13\0\0\0\x08\0'

# Python 2
key = '\x13\0\0\0\x08\0'
```

Comment: For the record, instead of `base64.b16decode(x)`, you can use, simply, `x.decode("hex")`. It lets you get by with one less import, at least. :)

Comment: `bytes.fromhex('130000000800')` in Python 3.

Answer (score 36):

Just use a `bytearray` (Python 2.6 and later) which represents a mutable sequence of bytes

```
>>> key = bytearray([0x13, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00])
>>> key
bytearray(b'\x13\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00')
```

Indexing get and sets the individual bytes

```
>>> key[0]
19
>>> key[1]=0xff
>>> key
bytearray(b'\x13\xff\x00\x00\x08\x00')
```

and if you need it as a `str` (or `bytes` in Python 3), it's as simple as

```
>>> bytes(key)
'\x13\xff\x00\x00\x08\x00'
```

Comment: Not so simple with 3.x; `fubar = str(key); print(len(key), len(fubar))` produces `6 38`. In any case (1) "string" is very vague terminology (2) if he wants mutability, he can mutate his original **list**

Comment: @John: Good point about `str` working differently for `bytearray` in Python 3 - fixed. I mentioned mutability mainly to distinguish it from `bytes`, but the point is also that you don't need to have an intermediate step of having your data in a `list` at all.

Comment: It's a fair chance that what the OP really needs is something like `struct.pack("<IH", 19, 8)` ...

Answer (score 6):

An alternative that also has the added benefit of easily logging its output:

```
hexs = "13 00 00 00 08 00"
logging.debug(hexs)
key = bytearray.fromhex(hexs)
```

allows you to do easy substitutions like so:

```
hexs = "13 00 00 00 08 {:02X}".format(someByte)
logging.debug(hexs)
key = bytearray.fromhex(hexs)
```

Answer (score 3):

Dietrich's answer is probably just the thing you need for what you describe, sending bytes, but a closer analogue to the code you've provided for example would be using the `bytearray` type.

```
>>> key = bytearray([0x13, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00])
>>> bytes(key)
b'\x13\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00'
>>>
```

Comment: Fine for Python 2.5 or earlier, but the built-in `bytearray` is really the way to go if you want, er, a byte array.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: Your answer needs another 2 edits: (1) mentions the array module (2) `bytearray('b', ...)` doesn't work. Or you could just delete it.

Comment: @John: thanks, fixed.  In the future, just go right ahead and make the edits yourself.