# How do I convert a binary image into an in-memory data structure in python?

Tags: python

Context:

- I am using python 2.6.5

Goal:

- Read a binary image file and represent it in-memory. Then run a checksum on it. Deliver the binary representation to be stored as a blob in mysql.

Comments:

- I have read this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380460/byte-array-in-python).
- I have looked at the [struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) module.
- I also have bumped into the [io](http://docs.python.org/library/io.html) module.
- With all the available options, I am not certain which is the best solution. The BytesIO data structure seems to be suitable for my needs. Which one do you think will meet my requirements ?

Comment: When you read the blob back from mysql, will you be working with it as an image or just writing it back to a file?

Comment: Please up vote and select one of the 2 below and select an answer if applicable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> from binascii import crc32
>>> with open(filename, "rb") as f:
...     data = f.read()
...
>>> crc32(data)
361260080
```

Comment: This calculates a checksum of the file, not the checksum of image data. . This means it will generate a different checksum for 2 .pngs with identical image but different metadata. Might be relevant

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend using PIL (Python Image Library)

http://effbot.org/imagingbook/pil-index.htm

Save it down to a string and then write to the db. Then you can use the string butter interface to PIL to read it back out.